# How to reason these Java generics syntax for return type?

Tags: java, generics

I come across this syntax in Java

```
ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object> builder = ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder()
```

On the left hand side I can understand the Builder takes two types String and Object. But the right hand sytax is confusing to me. 
As I read it

1. ImmutableMap.XXX // XXX should be property or a static method.
2. Well, I find `Immutable.<String, Object>` // How come XXX is now a `<String, Object>`, a generic type?
3. Next, `Immutable.<String, Object>builder();`  // Now, is this a builder() return type? That it will return `Immutable.<String, Object>`. How is builder behaving like a standalone function now.

You can see that I am bit stumped by this syntax in Java. How do I best understand these kind of syntaxes?

A simpler example being, in a unit test, I had to do.

```
expect(mockDao.findId(role, name)).andReturn(Optional.<Long>absent());
```

absent() is a generic static method of Optinal and I would understand if it were Optional.absent(), but making it `Optional.<Long>absent()` instead of `Optional<Long> Optional.absent()` confuses me a bit.

Any sources that I should look into to clarify my understanding of this concept?

Comment: Interesting.. It's apparently legal to add any generic type specification to any method call when the method is not generic. `System.out.<Integer>println("Hello!".<Void, Void>toString())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time, when a method is generic, for example:

```
public static <T> Optional<T> absent()
```

the compiler can automatically *infer* the right generic type from the context. For example:

```
Optional<String> opt = Optional.absent();
```

calls the generic static method `absent()` of Optional and the compiler infers the generic type of the method (String) from the type of the variable `opt` to which the result is assigned.

But sometimes, it can't infer it, or infers another types than the one you want, like in

```
Set<Object> set = Collections.singleton("foo");
```

To specify which generic type you want to call the method with, the syntax is to specify the generic type before the method name:

```
Set<Object> set = Collections.<Object>singleton("foo");
```

Comment: Thanks! That explains clearly. Why the quirk that type is given after Class. and before the method name? It could have been `<Object>Collections.singleton("foo")`  (Sort of like type casting) ?

Comment: What if you want to do `String foo = SomeClass.<Bar>bla().<Baz>bling().<Blub>bing().<String>bizz()`?

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I get the point. According to my thought process this could have been `<String>(<Blub>((<Baz>(<Bar>SomeClass.bla()).bling()).bing()).bizz())`

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply the type somehow.  If I have

```
public static <T> T getRandom(List<T> list) { ... }
```

which is a method to return a random element from a list, that type is inferred from the object I pass in:

```
List<String> list = // whatever
String randomString = getRandom(list); // <- the type String gets filled in here
```

But, if I have a situation where the type isn't able to be inferred, then it has to be supplied, and that awkward-looking "after the dot" syntax is Java's way of doing it.  It looks like `builder()` is a factory method for making a new `ImmutableMap.Builder`, but the method doesn't take anything so there's nothing to take the type from.